# Can't create cookie in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, setcookie

I'm having problems to create cookie in Laravel5. The code is below.

```
            $input = $request->input('first');

            if($request->hasCookie('first'))
            {
                return response()->json('ok');
            }
            else
            {
                Cookie::make('first', 'first', 1);
                return response()->json('no');
            }
```

I also tried this:

```
public function createCookie(CookieJar $cookieJar)
{
 $cookieJar->make('first', 'first', 1);
}
```

Nothing works for me, can someone illuminate me? 
Thanks in advance. When i try to var_dump and get the cookie value it gives me NULL.

Comment: Is it giving you an error, or are you just not able to read the cookie?

Comment: I can't read the cookie, when i dd($cokie) it gives me null, so the cookie is not created

Answer (score 2):

By doing this  `Cookie::make('first', 'first', 1);` , you are creating a cookie it doesn't mean it is already set. you have to send cookie with response.
use below code:

```
$cookie=Cookie::make('first', 'first', 1);
 return response()->json('no')->withCookie($cookie);
```

Comment: so i must send response with cookie in order to get cookie value?

Comment: cookies are stored in browser right !. so by sending response you are telling browser to keep this cookie.

Comment: @jignesh-solanki THANK YOU! Why is this not documented better.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are sent only a request after you created them.

An easier way to check if cookie exist or not is to check http headers in the browser or resources->cookies in Chrome.

Also you didn't provide the dd/var_dump code you used or neither why you need to use a new cookie instead of using Laravel `Session::flash`